# gcloud Admin API - Creating Cloud Run container

Tags: go, gcloud

I'm attemping to use the go api for gcloud to create a container.

I have a project set up:

```
$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID          NAME         PROJECT_NUMBER
sql-manager-293118  sql-manager  789332021319
```

Also my application default credentials are configured.

The below code runs fine, but at the call to create the service I get the below error:

```
<p>The requested URL <code>/v1alpha1/projects/sql-manager-293118/services?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I've also run simpler requests using the api (for example listing all the available locations for this given service), and have been able to retrun data without issue.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    // "sort"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "google.golang.org/api/run/v1alpha1"
)

const (
    createDefaultClientFlag = true
    scopes = run.CloudPlatformScope
    // List the Cloud Run services in this location
    serviceName = "test"
    locationsId = "us-central1"
    projectId = "sql-manager-293118"
    imageName = "gcr.io/cloudrun/hello"
)

func createDefaultClient(ctx context.Context) (*run.APIService, error) {
    return run.NewService(ctx)
}

func main() {
    // https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/run/v1#NewService
    var err error = nil
    var runService *run.APIService = nil

    ctx := context.Background()
    runService, err = createDefaultClient(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    projectsLocationsService := *run.NewProjectsLocationsService(runService)

    // Define the service to deploy
    tmpservice := &run.Service{
        ApiVersion: "serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1",
        Kind:       "Service",
        Metadata: &run.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      serviceName,
            Namespace: projectId,
        },
        Spec: &run.ServiceSpec{
            RunLatest: &run.ServiceSpecRunLatest{
                Configuration: &run.ConfigurationSpec{
                    RevisionTemplate: &run.RevisionTemplate{
                        Metadata: &run.ObjectMeta{
                            DeletionGracePeriodSeconds: 0,
                        },
                        Spec: &run.RevisionSpec{
                            Container: &run.Container{
                                Image: imageName,
                                Resources: &run.ResourceRequirements{
                                    Limits: map[string]string{"memory": "256Mi"},
                                },
                                Stdin:     false,
                                StdinOnce: false,
                                Tty:       false,
                            },
                            ContainerConcurrency: 80,
                            TimeoutSeconds:       300,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    createCall := projectsLocationsService.Services.Create("projects/" + projectId, tmpservice)
    service, err := createCall.Do()
    fmt.Println(service, err)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating new locationservice: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", service.Spec)
}
```

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the docs. Looking at the service's discovery doc ([link](https://run.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1alpha1)) and grep'ing `v1alpha1/{+parent}/services` suggests that the `parent` string should be `"^projects/[^/]+/locations/[^/]+$"`, i.e. `/projects/${PROJECT}/locations/us-central1/`. This got me a 400 (rather than 404). I assume (!?) there's an error in my `&run.Service`  too.

Answer (score 1):

DazWilkin was correct, I should have been using `/projects/${PROJECT}/locations/us-central1/`